# How to Switch schema from DataSource for Spring Batch

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, schema, spring-batch

I am struggling on getting JdbcBatchItemWriter to work with different database schemas. I have tried different approaches and nothing works:

> spring.datasource.schema=MYCUSTOMSCHEMA

wields

> "Property spring.datasource.schema with value 'class path resource 
>   [MYCUSTOMSCHEMA]' is invalid: The specified resource does not exist."

Trying SCHEMA.Table does not work either.

Any suggestions? I am using spring 2.1.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

> How to Switch schema from DataSource for Spring Batch

The `JdbcBatchItemWriter` is configured with a `DataSource` object, it does not really know which schema it is writing to. So to answer your question, you need to switch `DataSource` objects in your writer.

As a side note, `spring.datasource.schema` should point to a script containing DDL statements, not a schema name (in which case, you would use the `spring.datasource.name` property).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Neither Hikari or OracleData source exposes schema as a property to set. I was able to find that using table prefixes works.

Comment: @Danilo Silva- Could you please some code/configuration details?